# Open multiple windows in loop

Tags: javascript

I am having issues opening multiple windows in a correct order, no matter what I try it opens all windows simultaniously - which can be serveral hundred.  I am trying to open one window, do something, close window, repeat until all have opened.

```
var mission = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="/missions"]');
var i;

document.getElementById("sharebtnalliance").onclick = function shareMission(){
    for(i = 0; i < mission.length; i++){
        window.open(mission[i], "", "height: 80%; width: 80%;");
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.close();
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

The delay does not seem to kick in, 5 seconds would be long enough to do what needs doing before opening the next URL but it also does not close them - could be because the browser is struggling to keep up with so many opening pages.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use a timeout, you should probably wait for the window to be closed with something like this: N.B. This will only work if the URLs are on the same domain.

***CAVEAT:*** *THIS HAS NOT BEEN TESTED AND MAY REQUIRE SOME DEBUGGING*

```js
var mission = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="/missions"]');

document.getElementById("sharebtnalliance").onclick = async function shareMission(){
    for(let i = 0; i < mission.length; i++){
        await openWindowAsync(mission[i]);
    }
}

function openWindowAsync(url){
     return new Promise(resolve => {
         const w = window.open(url, "", "height: 80%; width: 80%;");
         w.addEventListener('close', resolve);
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you - URL's all on the same domain.  I will test it now.

Comment: I get  an unexpected token on `await openWindow(mission[i]);`

Comment: Check the name of the function, it's wrong in my example - FIXED

Comment: Even after your edit (I also tried the that), I get the same error

Comment: What browser (and version) are you trying this in?

Comment: Edge, I am using it in Tampermoney

Comment: What version is it?

Comment: Edge is 88.0.705.53 Tampermonkey is 4.11

Comment: That latest change you have made is working and better than where I was, each page opens and finishes loading before the next opens but I am needing to open //do something, close it, open next and so on

Comment: This should wait until the window to be closed so you can do something, then move on to next one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227964/discussion-between-sauced-apples-and-phuzi).